# What happens when I provide type hint but don't initialize?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have been after a way to provide none initialized instance variables to my class. I found that we can actually do that using type hinting without assigning anything to them. Which does not seem to create it in anyway. For example:

```
class T:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a: str
    
    def just_print(self):
        print(self.a)
    
    def assign(self):
        self.a = "test"
```

Now lets say I run this code:

```
t = T()
t.just_print()
```

It will raise an `AttributeError` saying `'T' object has not attribute 'a'`. Obviously, when I run this code, it prints `test`.

```
t = T()
t.assign()
t.just_print()
```

My question is, what happens behind the scene when I just do `a: str`? It doesn't get added to the class's attributes. But it doesn't cause any problem either. So... is it just ignored? This is python 3.8 by the way.

Comment: Your `init` declares a local variable `a`, not an instance variable `a`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Sorry, that was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed.

Comment: It does nothing, as you can see. Type hints don't do anything. They are *hints for the person reading the source code*. They are meant to be analyzed by third-party static analysis tools, like the static type checker `mypy`. Also, some libraries will use certain annotations for various effects, e.g. the built-in library `dataclasses`, but generally, just remeber, hints are meant to be hints

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So, would it be the same as as a comment? It really feels odd for it not to do anything.

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, **why** are you trying to do this? What exactly is the effect you expect? What could `t.just_print()` have done differently, other than throw an `AttributeError`?

Comment: @Mansour.M yes, they are pretty much like comments, as far as Python the language is concerned, You can do fancy things with them if you want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, sorry. Just got your update in the comment.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The reason I am doing this is for the next developer to know what else they can define other than the already defined attributes. To be honest, I was expecting it to throw a not initialized exception or something like Java.

Comment: @Mansour.M python is not like Java, it *doesn't have variable declarations*. There is no such thing as an "unitialized variable/attribute". Variables/attributes spring into existence *when you assign to them*. So in Python, you'll just get `NameError`s or `AttributeErrors`... which is pretty much the same behavior anyway

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, thanks. It kinda feels like a missed opportunity for Python to provide a more usable difference between None and not initialized though. But that may just be my opinion. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to type **annotations**, as defined by [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/):

```
my_var: int
```

Please note that type annotations differ from type **hints**, as defined by [PEP 428](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/):

```
def my_func(foo: str):
    ...
```

Type annotations have actual runtime effects. For example, the [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations) states:

> In addition, at the module or class level, if the item being annotated is a simple name, then it and the annotation will be stored in the `__annotations__` attribute of that module or class [...]

So, by slightly modifying your example, we get this:

```
>>> class T:
...    a: str
...    
>>> T.__annotations__
{'a': <class 'str'>}
```

Comment: Good info! Thanks. So, when it is a class variable it goes to `__annotations__` and it is called a type annotation. But what if it is an instance variable? Do we still call it type annotation? What happens to them in that case? It seems logical to assume they serve some purpose if the class variable does.

Comment: There is a thing called "instance variable annotation", you can read about it [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#class-and-instance-variable-annotations). It even covers your original use case (annotation inside `__init__()`)